# VC++ Error on template inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax

This is child's play, but I'm a bit of a vc n00b.

I get an error: `error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'`. on the second line of the following code:

```
template<int i, int j> 
class B : public A<i, j> { }

template<int i, int j> 
class A { }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the semi-colons and the declaration of A(just declare A before B to avoid writing the declaration):

```
template<int i, int j> 
class A { };

template<int i, int j> 
class B : public A<i, j> { };
```